# Mariadb 10.1.25: create type ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mariadb

cut and paste from the manual: 
CREATE TYPE UDT_1 AS CHAR(15) FINAL;

results in:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE UDT_1 AS CHAR(15) FINAL' at line 1

clean install. all global and schema privileges granted.  create view & create table work.

thanks for any insight.